# Having trouble with Selenium driver.find_elements_by_xpath

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I got the first two working, but I am having trouble with the last one. The HTML I am targeting looks like this

```
<div id="authn-username-wrapper">
                <div id="authn-username-input" class="ember-view placeholder-container"> <input id="identification" placeholder="Username" aria-label="Username" class="input placeholder-input ember-view ember-text-field">  <span class="placeholder-text">Username</span></div>
            </div>
```

Here's the log in page link https://portal.id.cps.edu/

The codes that I have tried are:

```
loginBox1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id ="identification"]')
```

and

```
loginBox1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id ="identification"]')
```

but I keep on getting the following error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id ="identification"]"}
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant page url if possible ?

Comment: Check if the element inside iframe

Comment: it could be due to iframe or multiple web elements present for identification id

Comment: How do I check for iframe-ing? I am not familiar with HTML beyond inspect element

Comment: do this //iframe in dev tools. also use @ to reply

Comment: @Dynasty2468 The site seems to be protected by some Rapid Identity. Which does not allow page to load when launched by selenium and it is detected by Rapid Identity. Hence the error, which is obvious.

Comment: @Dev but the page does load. I am having trouble getting the element

Comment: @Dynasty2468 For me it is not loading

Comment: @Dev seems to be loading on my end even in incognito mode. Maybe it's some outside issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need explicit waits like this :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get("https://portal.id.cps.edu/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "identification"))).send_keys('user name here')
```

this works in my local.